# Does a picture of the hierarchy of all objective-c classes exist?

Tags: objective-c, class

I have just learned that classes exist in a hierarchy. Every class has a superclass, its parent, exempt for the root class of the entire hierarchy, NSObject.  So NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray, which inherits from NSObject, and NSString inherits from NSObject and so forth.

So does anyone have a picture of all the inheritances?  I know there is so many, so it would be quite large, maybe impossible to list them all in one image.  But it would make an interesting reference.

Something like this is probably not necessary, but it would be interesting to see.

Thanks.

Comment: That would be too big, there are so many classes.You want all or just the most important ones?

Comment: Note that there would be multiple hierarchies, as there are multiple root classes in Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer:

[Cocoa Objective-C Hierarchy for Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroFoundation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000687-25735) in the "Foundation Framework Reference" shows the hierarchy of the Foundation classes.

Of course, there are many more frameworks defining classes that are derived from `NSObject` or `NSProxy`, but I don't know if similar pictures for these exist.